# How to remove brick step

Tags: brick, stairs, removal

I want to remove this bricks and mortar step. I have a brick bolster and hammer. Will that do the job? It looks like it isn't so well "stuck" at the bottom. Should I start there and see if the whole thing comes off or should I try and remove the mortar from between each brick, one at a time?
[image: brick step]

Comment: Hammer.  Chisel.  Swing.  Wanna spend money?  Rent jackhammer.  Too heavy to lift.

Comment: By 'too heavy to lift' I'm referring to the idea of starting at the bottom and seeing if the whole thing comes off.  You'll never lift that on your own as a single piece.

Comment: jam a crowbar under it and see if it lifts

Comment: I'm a bit nervous of power tools. It would be my first time :-) That's not saying I wouldn't give it a shot though.

Answer (score 4):

I would knock it apart for easier lifting. You could've done a little experimenting and probably had it done in the time it took to post this. :)